# Remove relative path via cmake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, cmakelists-options

I put a certain `header.h` file in `project/include/subfolder1`

And enter the following in `other.cpp` in another subfolder2

```
#include "../subfolder1/header.h"
```

But I hope to remove the `../subfolder1/` in `#include` via CMake
Make it like this:

```
#include "header.h"
```

But I am new to CMake and I need some hints, any help is greatly.

Below is my cmakelist.txt in `project`:

```
macro(addAllSubDirectory rootDir)
    FILE(GLOB children RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${rootDir} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${rootDir}/*)
    foreach(child ${children})
        if(IS_DIRECTORY ./${rootDir}/${child})
            add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/${rootDir}/${child})
            addAllSubDirectory(${rootDir}/${child})
        else()
            message("include ./${rootDir}/${child} Success.")
        endif()
    endforeach()
endmacro()

#===============================
# Init Project
#===============================
project(testProject)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

#===============================
# include
#===============================
addAllSubDirectory(appsMgr)
addAllSubDirectory(ctrlBase)
```

Comment: Use [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html). So something like `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}  PRIVATE ../subfolder1)`

Comment: @kaylum thx for ur great help, is work! but I cannot include other header files in `other.h` like `other.cpp`. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I realized, I just set the wrong path. it's work now!

Comment: I hope you've got a good reason to use this kind of macro. Doing this seems like a terrible idea to me except for possibly some extremely rare cases. Since you describe yourself as being new to CMake I'm almost certain this is none of those cases. Having to list a few (<= 20) subdirectories is not a good reason imho.